# unable to check for false value in mac bash

Tags: bash

I was trying to create a script that tells me if a bash command was successful or not. So I was testing value of variable `$?` after each command, the value of the variable `$?` is consistent, but then I am unable to check for false value in variable `$?`

ie. if I run a cp command

```
cp -av "a.." "b.."
echo "$?"
```

if copy is successful: `$? = 0`
else: `$? = 1`

Suppose cp throw an error then `$? = 1`

when I try to do `if [ "$?" != 0 ]` the script will just ignore the instruction, what am I doing wrong.

I also tried: `if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]` with no luck.

Comment: Are you testing it after the `echo` command? If so, you're testing the exit status of `echo`. Instead of testing `$?`, you can look at the exit status directly: `if cp -av 'a..' 'ba..'; then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` itself resets the value of `$?`, you need to check its value (or at least save it) immediately after running `cp`.

```
cp -av "a.." "b.."
cp_result=$?
if [ "$cp_result" != 0 ]; then
   ...
```

If all you care about is whether `cp` succeeded, you can use `cp` directly as the condition to test.

```
if cp -av "a.." "b.."; then
  echo "cp succeeded"
else
  echo "cp failed"
fi
```